# How to alias containing class, in a method used in pytest parameters?

Tags: python, scope, pytest, alias

I want to alias the class name (Short = LongClassName), in a method meant to be used in the parameters of pytest. Inside the aliased class.

The constants cannot be imported from the code under test because the code under test is not Python, and all supporting data is supposed to be in the class containing the tests (a well-meant convention). But please don't focus on that.

I have tried several approaches, see the code:

```py
import pytest
from random import choice as randchoice

class TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention():
    SOMETHING_X1 = 0x04  # yes they must be inside THIS class (or inner class)
    SOMETHING_X2 = 0x05
    SOMETHING_Y1 = 0x06
    SOMETHING_Y2 = 0x07
    SOMETHING_Z1 = 0x08
    SOMETHING_Z2 = 0x09

    def randNonXThing(self):
        """ Instance method is useless for pytest params """
        return randchoice([self.SOMETHING_Y1, self.SOMETHING_Y2, self.SOMETHING_Z1,
                           TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention.SOMETHING_Z2])

    @staticmethod
    def randNonXThingMagicNumbers():
        """ Works but so bleh... """
        return randchoice([0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09])

    @staticmethod
    def randNonXThingTooHopeful():
        """ NameError: name 'SOMETHING_Y1' is not defined """
        return randchoice([SOMETHING_Y1, SOMETHING_Y2, SOMETHING_Z1, SOMETHING_Z2])

    @staticmethod
    def randNonXThingSesquipedalian():
        """  NameError on 'TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention' """
        return randchoice([TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention.SOMETHING_Y1,
                           TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention.SOMETHING_Y2,
                           TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention.SOMETHING_Z1,
                           TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention.SOMETHING_Z2])

    @staticmethod
    def randNonXThingAliased():
        """  NameError on 'TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention' """
        TUC = TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention
        return randchoice([TUC.SOMETHING_Y1, TUC.SOMETHING_Y2,
                           TUC.SOMETHING_Z1, TUC.SOMETHING_Z2])

    # TCl = TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention  # Also NameError

    @classmethod
    def randNonXThingAsClassMethod(cls):
        """ OK so far, but NameError when I use the class name in params... """
        return randchoice([cls.SOMETHING_Y1, cls.SOMETHING_Y2, cls.SOMETHING_Z1, cls.SOMETHING_Z2])


    @pytest.mark.parametrize("theXThing, "\
                            +"theOtherThing, "\
                            +"yetAnotherThing",
        [
            (
                randchoice([SOMETHING_X1, SOMETHING_X2]),  # this works but could get too long
                randNonXThingMagicNumbers(),
                randNonXThingMagicNumbers(),
            ),
        ])
    def test_theThings(self, theXThing, theOtherThing, yetAnotherThing):
        TCl1 = TestClass_WithASesquipedalianNameMandatedByConvention  # no problems here
        pass
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.12.0
$ python -m pytest --version
pytest 7.4.3
```

How to get close to using something like 'randNonXThingAliased()' instead of 'randNonXThingMagicNumbers()' in the parameters?

Comment: If true, it isn't shameful to answer "you can't"...